# How to use private enum values that are not accessible by Enum.__members__?

Tags: python, enums, private

With an Enum object as such:

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    _citrus = {orange, lemon}

    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in self.citrus
```

when we try to check its member:

```
>>> Fruits.__members__.keys()
dict_keys(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon', '_citrus'])
```

we get all possible Enum values. Is there a way to declare private vs public enums where some specific values are private and not accessible by `Enum.__members__`?

It's possible to do this:

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    _citrus = {orange, lemon}

    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in self.citrus
    
    @classmethod
    def values(cls):
        return set(k for k in cls.__members__.keys() if not k.startswith('_'))
```

Usage:

```
>>> Fruits.values()
{'apple', 'banana', 'lemon', 'orange'}
```

**Are there some other way to have restricted members access?**

**Are there examples of private vs public members in Python's Enum?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `property` for this problem, like this:

```py
class Fruits(str, Enum):
    apple = "apple"
    banana = "banana"
    orange = "orange"
    lemon = "lemon"

    @property
    def _citrus(self):
        return {self.__class__.orange, self.__class__.lemon}

    def is_citrus(self):
        return self in self._citrus
    

print(Fruits.orange.is_citrus())
# True

print(Fruits.__members__.keys())
dict_keys(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'lemon'])
```

Comment: Does this really work, if the docs say "will be removed from the final class"? Will `self in self._citrus` work?

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, the attribute is removed completely.

Comment: But this kinda works, although the Enum object can't be set to _citrus, `x = Fruits.lemon; x.is_citrus();`

Comment: The only logical way would be to hardcode the values in `is_citrus` function, but then doing so there would be no need of `_citrus` variable

Comment: @alvas check the edit, this should work - even if `_citrus` is not anymore a private variable, but it's missing from `__members__` and `is_citrus` method is working

Comment: Please remove the mention of `_ignore_` since it doesn't work for this use-case.

Comment: @EthanFurman you're right, in this case `_ignore_` is useless, I changed my answer